# Spring Data Elasticsearch: Understanding path.home

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am following [Spring Data Elasticsearch Turorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-elasticsearch-tutorial).

In section 2.3. Java Configuration, there is:

```
@Value("${elasticsearch.home:/usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/5.6.0}")
private String elasticsearchHome;
```

which is used in:

```
@Bean
public Client client() {
    Settings elasticsearchSettings = Settings.builder()
      .put("client.transport.sniff", true)
      .put("path.home", elasticsearchHome)
      .put("cluster.name", clusterName).build();
    TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(elasticsearchSettings);
    client.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), 9300));
    return client;
}
```

First, I din't understand why the client needs the installation directory of Elasticsearch. Second, I don't have Elasticsearch installed on the client computer. It's installed on a remote server. So what should I do with this settig - `path.home`?

(Of course I will change "127.0.0.1" too).

Comment: This tutorial is outdated. The transport client is deprecated too. Please have a look on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53423682/migrating-from-elastic-node-client-to-transport-or-rest-client/53426630#53426630

Comment: although thre Transport client is deprecated in ES 7, it will be available until ES 8 is released. And Spring Data Elasticsearch will support it until it's removed from Elasticsearch.